# Schiehallion experiment data

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

I am trying to write an exercise in which students need to calculate the density of earth following a procedure "inspired" in the [Schiehallion experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schiehallion_experiment).
My idea was to have the derive the following equation:

$$\rho_E=\rho_M\frac{V_M}{V_E}\left(\frac{R_E}{d}\right)^2\frac{1}{\tan\theta}$$

where $\rho_E$  and $\rho_M$ are the densities of Earth and of the mountain, $V_E$ and $V_M$ are the volumes, $R_E$ is the radius of earth, $d$ the distance between the pendulum and the centre of the mountain, $\theta$ the angle of the pendulum.

So far I have been able to find that $\rho_M=2500 kg/m^3$ and $\theta= 11.6''$. I also know that the result obtained was $\rho_E=4500 kg/m^3$. Therefore, I need at least one more datum. Does anyone know what was the value of $V_m$ used?

Comment: Read the article https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rstl.1775.0050

Comment: @AlexTrounev From what I could see, that information is not in the article.